# Shell Script to extract only file name

Tags: linux, shell, basename

I have file format like this  (publishfile.txt)

```
drwxrwx---+  h655201 supergroup          0  2019-04-24  09:16  /data/xyz/invisible/se/raw_data/OMEGA
drwxrwx---+  h655201 supergroup          0  2019-04-24  09:16  /data/xyz/invisible/se/raw_data/sample
drwxrwx---+  h655201 supergroup          0  2019-04-24  09:16  /data/xyz/invisible/se/raw_data/sample(1)
```

I just want to extract the name **OMEGA****, sample, sample(1)** How
can I do that I have used **basename** in my code but it doesn't work in for loop. Here is my sample code

```
for line in $(cat $BASE_PATH/publishfile.txt)
do 
      FILE_PATH=$(echo "line"| awk '{print  $NF}' )
done
FILE_NAME=($basename  $FILEPATH)
```

But this code also doesn't wor when used outside for loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
awk -F / '{ print $NF }' "$BASE_PATH"/publishfile.txt
```

This simply says that the delimiter is a slash and we want the last field from each line.

You should basically never run Awk on each input line in a shell `while read` loop (let alone [a `for` loop)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor); Awk itself does this by default, much faster and better than the shell.

Comment: this doesn't work if the file contains something like: `drwxrwx---+  h655201 supergroup          0  2019-04-24  09:16  sample` (i.e. a filepath without slash `/` char). You are correct with all other remarks! `awk` itself does the loop, etc. Using `awk` or `sed` is indeed a better solution!

Comment: Not directly, though it would not be very hard to adapt (try -F `[/ \t]'`)

Comment: How can I use in a way that file name is separated by comma ? Like sample,sample1

Comment: See the section _Parameter Expansion_ in the [POSIX shell specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html). If this doesn't answer your case, please ask a **new** question here, where you specify exactly the format of your input, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: If you are asking how to provide that sort o| output, the Awk script can easily be changed to use `printf` instead of `print`. If you are asking about input, I absolutely agree with the previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your code above you have a typo.  Your code reads:

```
    FILE_NAME=($basename  $FILEPATH)
```

but it should read

```
    FILE_NAME=$(basename  $FILEPATH)
```

That should work fine in or outside of a loop

Comment: I have tried    FILE_NAME=$(basename  $FILEPATH) this but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you post the actual code where you tried that and it didn't work?

Comment: Properly speaking you should also quote `"$FILEPATH"` but of course if you kept the buggy `for` loop it will be too late to actually fix any quoting problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sh
cat $BASE_PATH/publishfile.txt | awk '{print $7}' | sed 's/.*\///'
```

the output will be:

```
OMEGA
sample
sample(1)
```

UPDATE: I guess `cat x.txt | sed 's/.*\///'` will still work, if all your files, folders contain at least 1 slash (`/`).

For the commands used, the manuals are: [cat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html), [awk](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html), [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)

Comment: in the for loop line ?

Comment: The [`cat` is useless.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: yes, you can redirect the output, that's true, it may also be a little bit more efficient too. Probably depends how big the file is.